# The irb interface can not ping in EX4300 itself

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

In my Juniper EX4300 I created a irb.2 with address `10.10.10.110/24`

```
irb {
    unit 2 {
        family inet {
            address 10.10.11.110/24;  // the snapshot is wrong, I changed to 10.10.11.110/24 now
        }
    }
}
```

and I added vlan:

```
vlans {
    vlan2 {
        vlan-id 2
        l3-interface irb.2
    }
}
```

but I can not ping the IP address in the EX4300 switch itself.

---

**EDIT-01**

I use  `run show vlans` get bellow output:

```
Routing instance    VLAN name     Tag    Interfaces
default-switch      default       1      
                                         ae1.0
default-switch      vlan2         2    
                                         ae1.0
```

I use the `run show interfaces irb.2 terse`, I get

```
Interface       Admin       Link    Proto    Local    Remote
irb.2           up          down    inet     10.10.11.110/24
```

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into the question using the Preformatted-text feature `{ }`.

Comment: You can't ping this address from switch itself or from another device?

Comment: from switch itself

Comment: This is likely because the interface is down. Did you check the interface status? Is there a physical interface mapped to this VLAN UP? What's the result of the commands "run show interfaces vlan.2 terse" and "run show  vlans"?

Comment: @JFL see my updated post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use the run show interfaces irb.2 terse, I get

```
> Interface       Admin       Link    Proto    Local    Remote irb.2    
>                 up          down    inet     10.10.11.110/24
```

You can see that the Interface status is "link down". So your interface is effectively down and this is perfectly normal that you can't ping its IP address.

You have to bring the interface UP, this imply to bring UP at least one physical interface on which the VLAN is configured. Either an interface with this VLAN configured in mode access, or a trunk port on which the VLAN is allowed.